# Converting York Lava function to Kansas Lava

Tags: haskell, hdl, lava

I have here a York Lava function that I want to rewrite in Kansas Lava. But it doesn't want to work and I don't know I should do it actually.
Can someone help me with this please?

```
{-Serial In - Parallel Out shiftregister. The serial bit is inserted at
the least significant bit position. The data is shifted LSB -> MSB
each and every clock cycle-}

sipo :: Int   -- ^ The number of bits in the output word.
     -> Bit   -- ^ The input bit.
     -> [Bit] -- ^ The output word.
sipo 1 inp = [inp]
sipo n inp = inp : rest
  where
    inp' = delay low inp
    rest = sipo (n-1) inp'
```

This above function gives me these correct results for some examples:

```
n = 3
inp = high
out = [high, low, low]

n= 5
inp = high
out = [high, low, low, low, low]
```

Now I've tried to write this in Kansas Lava, their is a delay function, but I get weird results.
This code below generates me, with the same parameters as the first example:

```
n = 3
inp = high
out = [high?, high., high!] (don't know what that means)

sipo :: (Clock clk)
     => Int               -- ^ The number of bits in the output word.
     -> Signal clk Bool     -- ^ The input bit.
     -> [Signal clk Bool]   -- ^ The output word.
sipo 1 inp = [inp]
sipo n inp = inp : rest
  where
    inp' = delay inp
    rest = sipo (n-1) inp'
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what the correct output should be?

Comment: n stands for how big the list wil be

inp is the input in low or high

The output is than inp ++ n times low values
out = [inp, low, low, low, ..., n]

Example: n = 2
inp = high
out = [high, low]

Second example: n = 5
inp = low
out = [low, low, low, low, low]

Comment: (1) Are you sure the final snippet matches the error you pasted above it? I can't see how specialising `i` to `CLK` would lead to `Couldn't match expected type '[Signal i0 Bool]' with actual type 'Signal clk0 a0'.` (2) Which type does GHC(i) infer for `sipo` if you momentarily remove the signature?

Comment: Ok I was forgot to put something in comment in my code, so that error is not applied on this piece of code.

But I don't get the right output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your code works exactly as expected.**

Trying your function out in the simulator from GHCi, the result is:

```
*Main> sipo 3 (high :: Signal CLK Bool)
[high,? | high .,? | ? | high .]
```

The way to read it is:

```
 sipo 3 high !! 0 = high
 sipo 3 high !! 1 = ?    | high
 sipo 3 high !! 2 = ?    | ?    | high
```

This output from the Lava simulator means the first output is `high` in the first cycle, and there's no simulator input to tell futher values. Similarly, the second output is undefined in the first cycle and `high` in the second; and the third output is undefined for two cycles and `high` in the third.

This makes perfect sense, since the second output is not set to anything in the first cycle: the delayed input signal hasn't had time yet to get there.

The reason the result is different from York Lava is that York Lava's `delay` primitive seems to take an extra value to be used before the first clock cycle. I'm not sure that is synthesizable, though.